# Saving a picture path in MySQL database, and then pulling that data to display picture?

Tags: php, mysql, database, image

I have a MySQL database where I have a table ITEMS and column PICTUREPATH. The Picture path lists "localhost/firstimage.jpg" and so on.  In my PHP script, I've added some code to what I thought would work, but it's not. I'm fetching the picturepath but it's literally giving me the text "localhost/firstimage.jpg" rather than the actual image. Here is what my code looks like...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['picturepath'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

How can I add this into the code so the picture actually displays, not the text name of the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "<td align='center'><img src=\"" . $row['picturepath'] . "\" /></td>";
```

Comment: Adding the \" now displays a broken image icon. Better than what I had. Any other ideas? In my database, I have the location as localhost/firstimage.jpg - Is this wrong?

Comment: yes remove localhost just the relative image path so firstimage.jpg. later if you move your db to a server it won't break.